# Issue with set_array in python2 vs python3 when making 2D animations

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I've always made 2D animations of geographic data in the same way.

First I make the plot using the first "frame" of the data (data0 here):

```
    img = ax.pcolormesh(data0.lon.values, data0.lat.values, data0.x.values, cmap='viridis')
```

I then call FuncAnimation and pass the data in:

```
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(monthly_data.time.size), fargs=(fig, img, monthly_data))
```

and then use set_array to update the img object with the next frame

```
    img.set_array(ma.masked_invalid(this_data[:-1,:-1].ravel()))
```

This has always worked perfectly in python2 but I'm running into issues with python3. The result ends up with a "skewed" map and I think I've narrowed this down to set_array behaving differently with a QuadMesh object in py3 but I can't find any information on how set_array might have changed.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem- Here's what happended

You shouldn't define the initial quadmesh with X,Y arrays that match the size of the data matrix.  Doing this will clip your quadmesh in size to one row/col shorter than your dataset.

From the [Docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html):

*The dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C. Alternatively, X, Y and C may have equal dimensions, in which case the last row and column of C will be ignored.*

When you use:

*qm.set_array(new_array)*

You're tossing the flattened array into a constructor that will place the values in order, but is expecting a different size array.  Rather than an error, you get a quadmesh where the last consecutive element from each column is placed in the next row, creating the distorted mesh.

Define the original with an properly-spaced extra row and column or when using set_array() manually adjust them to match the smaller quadmesh.